# Javascript show message if total=x

Tags: javascript

HTML/Java noobie here so please bear with me. I have multiple quantity selectors on a page and then a javascript that takes the sum of all of the values.

```
<label for="quantity">Option 1: </label>
<input class="product-selector-field" onblur="findTotal()" min="0" type="number" id="quantity1" name="quantity" value="0" />
<br><br>      

<label for="quantity">Option 2: </label>
<input class="product-selector-field" onblur="findTotal()" min="0" type="number" id="quantity2" name="quantity" value="0" />
<br><br>

Total Selected : <input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly = true/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('quantity');
  var tot=0;

  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to display an error message if the sum is not equal to 15.

I've tried adding this to the script but I haven't had any success...

```
<span id="errorMessage">Error</span>

If (tot!=15) {
  document.getElementById('errorMessage').removeClass("hide")
} else {    
  document.getElementByID.addClass
}
```

This code is on a separate CSS file:

```
  .hide {
        display: none !important;
  }
```

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: `If` should be `if` (lowercase i), and a DOM node has no `.removeClass()` method. It should be `.classList.remove("hide")`. And `document.getElementByID.addClass` isn't at all a reasonable bit of code.

Comment: Lesson 1: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Take a look at your browser's error console and see if it's telling you anything.

Comment: `document.getElementById('errorMessage').classList.toggle("hide", tot == 15)` This is simpler anyway.

Comment: @squint Thank you, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `oninput` instead of `onblur`, it's better
2. You should use `isNaN` to check if a value is valid number or not. (keep in mind `if(0)` is `false`) so `0`s will be excluded even if they're valid numbers)
3. The error message should be hidden initialy (having the class `hidden` at start). Depending on what you need of course, my opinion is it should be hidden.
4. DOM elements don't have such function as `.removeClass` or `.addClass` (those are jQuery's). Use `.classList.add` and `.classList.remove` or `.className =` instead!

```css
#errorMessage {
  color: red;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="quantity">Option 1:</label>
<input class="product-selector-field" oninput="findTotal()" min="0" type="number" id="quantity1" name="quantity" value="0" />
<br>
<br>

<label for="quantity">Option 2:</label>
<input class="product-selector-field" oninput="findTotal()" min="0" type="number" id="quantity2" name="quantity" value="0" />
<br>
<br>Total Selected :
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly=true/>
<span id="errorMessage" class="hidden">Error</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function findTotal() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('quantity');
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (!isNaN(arr[i].value)) // use isNaN to check if it is a valid number or not (because if(0) is false so 0 will be excluded)
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;

    var errorElement = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
    if (tot !== 15)
      errorElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    else
      errorElement.classList.add('hidden');
  }
</script>
```